# How to select concentric elements of a 2d matrix in javascript?

Tags: javascript

How to select/group together concentric elements of a 2d matrix?

Following is the code for creating a 2d array.

```
function Create2DArray(rows) {
  var arr = [];

  for (var i=0;i<rows;i++) {
     arr[i] = [];
  }

  return arr;
}
```

imagine an element at the centre of the matrix with address `i,j`.

How can I separate out the cells in the following manner?

[image]

such that only the elements highlighted are grouped together / separated out.

It would be great if a mathematical algorithm, rather than looping a lot. (as this will be more efficient)

**NOTE**

The above approach works only if the matrix is of odd size i.e. `3 x 3` , `5 x 5`, `7 x 7` etc... So if there is a way to implement this for even numbered matrices greater than 3, please suggest that too (for matrices greater than or equal to 4 there is a subset of odd sized matrix which we can use of to implement the above algorithm & discard the remaining)..

Please use math/ indices to cut out concentric cells, rather than using traditional iterators, or anything similar, as this allows faster calculations (...as you can start from the central address (or index) and decrement/increment out) (if possible, if not possible you can suggest any approach)

the possible output can be either an array or an object of corresponding cell addresses

like spanning like this:

```
index/key 1-> level 1 concentric cells
index/key 2-> level 2 concentric cells
index/key 3-> level 3 concentric cells
...
```

or possible output can be just a way of traversing each successive levels rather than grouping out the concentric cells; Like if concentric cells in level one is traversed the say `alert(level 1)`... then after level two `alert(level 2)` and so on...

Comment: Are you looking for the solution with loops also?

Comment: yes. sure. every suggestions are invited.

Answer (score 0):

You could start from the center point (can be any point with row/column) and then you loop each row and column and do the checking based on the space from that center point.

```js
function genMatrix(rows, cols) {
  return Array.from(Array(rows), () => {
    return Array(cols).fill(0)
  })
}

function select(matrix, [cRow, cCol], space = 0) {
  for (let i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      if (space === 0) {
        // for center point
        if (i == cRow && j == cCol) {
          matrix[i][j] = 3
        }
      } else {
        // for horizontal points
        if (i == cRow - space || i == cRow + space) {
          if (j <= cCol + space && j >= cCol - space) {
            matrix[i][j] = 3
          }
        }

        // for vertical points
        if (j == cCol - space || j == cCol + space) {
          if (i <= cRow + space && i >= cRow - space) {
            matrix[i][j] = 3
          }
        }

      }
    }
  }

  return matrix
}


const center = [3, 3];

const result = [
  select(genMatrix(7, 7), center),
  select(genMatrix(7, 7), center, 1),
  select(genMatrix(7, 7), center, 2),
  select(genMatrix(7, 7), center, 3)
]

// for the demo
result.forEach(matrix => {
  matrix.forEach(row => console.log(JSON.stringify(row)))
  console.log('-'.repeat(20))
})
```

Comment: and what if this is not an odd sized matrix??

Comment: I mean for eg. for matrices of order <=4 we can have sub matrices with odd order. So can you extend the code to include that case also?

Comment: Doesn't it work already https://jsfiddle.net/nmgurcyL/2/

Comment: Really?? does this supports even numbered matrices also??

Comment: Is there a way to separate each concentric level  out??

Comment: What do you mean by that?

Comment: Is there a way to separate each concentric level out (like separate collections)??

Comment: So you mean that each level is an array of points where each point is [row, column] sub array, something like that?

Comment: yes, exactly like that also... like extracting out only those elements or cells or address that corresponds to a particular concentric level

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222833/discussion-between-mex-and-nenad-vracar).

Comment: Well yes you could just create one object and then in each function call (for each level) you add those items ([row, column]) so something like this https://jsfiddle.net/nmgurcyL/4/. Now in that object you have only those targeted cells fro each level.

Comment: Is it possible to do this without any loops...?? like using maths... (cause the addresses can be calculated)... just curious !!

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think it would be a different approach

Comment: One more doubt is that ... is it possible to skip cells that are occupied.(for eg. if I occupy some random cells with some numbers, is it possible to skip them... without checking them).... I want this because this will be a O(n) complex... so if we can skip occupied cells without looking in to them or not consider them while looping we can improve performance... is that possible??

Comment: @mex You could try something like this instead https://jsfiddle.net/95vbam1e/1/ . This solution should have better performance.

Comment: ok. great. along with the how can I splice out occupied cells... if I'm filling them... along each iteration

Comment: If you splice one cell (column) then the calculation for the remaining cells will be wrong because it expects the fixed size of matrix. Not sure why you need to splice them out, you can just select, modify, clone then when you iterate the selected cells for some specific layer based on the row/column values.

Comment: Can you please come over the chat?